# Mulitple teemaps on one page using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I'm trying to make a page with multiple treemaps graphs on one page.  So far I've been able to do that using a function which I pass json to.  But when I've tried to change values in the treemaps I run into all sorts of problems.  Here is the function which creates the treemaps and you can see the start of an on change function:

```
TreeMap.prototype.drawSystem = function(json, key) {
    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .size([this.d3.width, this.d3.height])
        .sticky(false)
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    var div = d3.select("#systems").append("div")
        .attr("id", key)
        .style("position", "relative")
        .style("width", this.d3.width + "px")
        .style("height", this.d3.height + "px")
        .style("padding", this.d3.padding + "px");

    div.data([json]).selectAll("div")
        .data(treemap.nodes)
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .style("background", 'red')
        .call(this.cell)
        .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name + '    Memory: ' + d.size + 'GB'+ '    Disk: ' + d.disk + 'GB'; });

    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change(key) {
            console.log(d3);
            console.log(div);
            console.log(key);
        //div.data(treemap.value(
        //    function (d) {
        //        return d.disk;
        //    }
        //)).transition().duration(150).call(this.cell).text(
        //    function (d) {
        //    return d.children ? null : d.name + '    Disk: ' + d.disk + 'GB';
        //}
        //);
    });


};
```

This is the Json i use:

```
{
    "global1": {
        "name": "P",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "red",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "ADMI - fnet-admi-uat",
                        "size": 20.1,
                        "disk": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ALEV - fnet-alev3z1",
                        "size": 13.1,
                        "disk": 27
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "global2": {
        "name": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "red",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "this is another co",
                        "size": 20.1,
                        "disk": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "this is tomshting",
                        "size": 13.1,
                        "disk": 27
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Calling the function like so:

```
            for (key in data) {
                if (typeof data[key] !== 'function') {
                    this.drawSystem(data[key], key);
                }
            }
```

I can see where I'm going wrong, i.e. reusing variables to create divs etc.  But I'm not sure how to overcome this.

Has anyone had any experience in doing something like this before?  If so do you have any pointers to send me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout the video and code in the post, I found them very helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/TMKw4GildLI